# Need help with proof of property related to group rings.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, finite-groups

Suppose $G = \langle g \rangle$ is a cyclic group of order $n$, $k$ is an algebraically closed field, and $w \in k$ a primitive $n$th root of unity.

I want to show that in the group algebra $k[G]$, the elements

$$e_1 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n g^k \quad \text{and} \quad e_j = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} (w^{j} g)^k \quad (j = 2, ..., n)$$ satisfy $e_i \cdot e_j = \delta_{ij} e_i$ and $\sum_i e_i = \mathbb{1}_{k[G]}$ in $k[G]$.

---

The only thing I have been able to prove is $e_1^2 = e_1$, but I don't know what to do for the rest.

Comment: $e_1$ should have the $\frac{1}{n}$ normalization too, right?

Comment: @Chris Yes, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Exponent of $\omega$ should be $j-1$ I believe.

Comment: Hi Steve, no it's just $j$.

Comment: That would imply $e_1=e_n$, no?

Comment: @SteveD: Oh you're right, and it's a typo coming from where I copied the problem. Then I would think too that the exponent must be $j-1$.

Comment: I would suggest doing the multiplication by expanding it out, then grouping things by each $g^k$. It will be easier to help from there (or you might figure it out yourself!).

Comment: @SteveD Do you have a suggestion for how to prove that the sum is equal to $1$? I understand I have to use that the sum of the $nth$ roots of unity is $0$, but am not sure how to use this to prove the result. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Same as for the product: group things by $g^k$.  Note that something special happens when $k=n$...

Comment: You'll need Cauchy's product formula probably : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product

Comment: Since $w^n=1$, $e_n=\left( \frac{1}{n}\sum_{l=1}^n{\left( w^ng \right) ^l} \right) =\left( \frac{1}{n}\sum_{l=1}^n{g^l} \right) =e_1$.   Thus $e_ne_1=e_1e_1=e_1\ne 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For notational convenience I will write
$$ e_i = \sum_{r=0}^{n-1} (\omega^ig)^r $$
So that "my" $\{e_0,\ldots,e_{n-1}\}$ is "your" $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$.

We can compute $e_ie_j$ by looking at the coefficient of each $g^k$, which is
$$ n^{-2}\sum_{r+s=k} \omega^{ri+sj} = n^{-2}\sum_{r+s=k}\omega^{ri+si}\omega^{sj-si}=n^{-2}\omega^{ik}\sum_{s=0}^{n-1}(\omega^{j-i})^s$$
Since $\omega^{j-i}$ is an $n$th root of unity, this last sum is $0$ when $j\neq i$ and is $n$ when $j=i$.

Similarly we can compute $\sum e_i$. The coefficient of $g^k$ is then
$$ n^{-1}\sum_{t=0}^{n-1} \omega^{tk} = n^{-1}\sum_{t=0}^{n-1}(\omega^k)^t $$
This last sum is $0$ when $k\neq0$ and $n$ when $k=0$.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, I think $e_j$ should be $e_j=\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n{\left( w^{j-1}g \right) ^k}$. Otherwise, $e_1=e_n$.

**The first part : $e_ie_i=\delta_{ij}e_i$**

Let we calculate $e_ie_j.$

By the definition, we obtain
\begin{align*}
e_ie_j&=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n{w^{ki-k}g^k}\sum_{l=1}^n{w^{jl-l}g^l}
\\
&=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{s\ge 2}{\sum_{k+l=s}{w^{ki-k}w^{jl-l}g^s}}=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{s\ge 2}{g^s(\sum_{k+l=s,1\le k\le n,1\le l\le n}{w^{ki+jl-s}})}.
\end{align*}

We just calculate the coefficients of $g^p$ and $g^{n+p}$ where $1\le p\le n$.

The coefficients of $g^p$ is :
$$\sum_{k+l=p,1\le k\le n,1\le l\le n}{w^{ki+jl-p}}=\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}{w^{ki+j\left( p-k \right) -p}}.$$

The coefficients of $g^{n+p}$:
$$\sum_{k+l=n+p,1\le k\le n,1\le l\le n}{w^{ki+jl-p}}=\sum_{p\le k\le n}{w^{ki+j\left( p-k \right) -p}}.$$

Since $g^n=e$ and $w^n=1$, the sum of coefficients of $g^p$ and $g^{n+p}$ is

$$\sum_{1\le k\le n}{w^{ik+j\left( p-k \right) -p}}=w^{jp-p}\sum_{1\le k\le n}{w^{ik-jk}}.$$

Let $s=i-j$ and define $f(p)=w^{jp-p}\sum_{1\le k\le n}{w^{ik-jk}}.$

If $s\ne 0$, $f(p)=w^{jp-p}\sum_{1\le k\le n}{w^{sk}}=w^{jp-p}\frac{w^s\left( 1-w^{sn} \right)}{1-w^s}=0.$

If $s=0$, $f\left( p \right) =\sum_{1\le k\le n}{w^{i\left( p-1 \right)}}.$

By the above arument, if $i\ne j$, then the sum of coefficients of $g^p$ and $g^{n+p}$, where $1\le p\le n$ are all euqal to $0$. This shows $e_ie_j=0$ if $i\ne j$.

If $i=j$, $e_i^2=e_ie_i=\dfrac{1}{n^2}\sum_{1\le p\le n}\sum_{1\le k\le n}{w^{i\left( p-1 \right)}g^p}=\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{1\le p\le n}{w^{i\left( p-1 \right)}g^p}=e_i.$

**The second part** :$\sum_{1\le i\le n}e_i=1_{k[G]}:$

For $\forall x\in K[G]$, we write $x=\sum_{1\le i\le n}a_ig^i$.

It is similar and you can also calculate the coefficients on both side of $$\sum_{1\le i\le n}{e_i}x=x.$$